# enable a disabled queue on Google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

A queue went into disabled mode on dashboard, the tasks added to that queue are not being executed.

```
QueueName   MaximumRate BucketSize  OldestTask  TasksinQueue    RuninLastMinute
default  1/s     5.0         0   0
mailsend     15/m    5.0         0   0
livefeed     0/s     5.0         0   0 (Disabled)
```

Checked the documentation but could not find any thing related to this.

Can any one help with this, the queue name is placed in many parts of the code and could not be changed in one push.

Any body can help with recipe to bring the queue  back live..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have uploaded a different version that doesn't have the recipe queue in the queue.yaml

Deploying this version again with recipe in queue.yaml should re-enable it

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/status/appengine

I guess there's a problem.. Im not sure though...